# Pronunciation of "xe" and "xyr"

Tags: pronunciation, personal-pronouns, gender-neutral

I've been reading a book that includes extraterrestrials that shift from female to male during the course of their lives. During the transition phase, the other characters in the book use the neutral pronouns "xe" and "xyr" to refer to them.

What would be an appropriate pronunciation for these?

Comment: X in front of an English word generally makes the Z sound – but it's hard to know in this case.

Comment: Pronouncing the 'x' like in Spanish would be *so great*, though.

Comment: "xe" is probably best pronounced "they" and "xyr" as "their" ;)

Comment: Personally, when I form neutral pronouns, I pronounce "x" as "sh": "xe (she) said", "I saw xem (shem)", "xer (sher) name", "that is xers (shers)", helps xerself (sherself)".

Comment: How do you pronounce Xerox?

Comment: According to a friend of mine who prefers these pronouns, @J.R. is correct-- the "x" is pronounced like a "z".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

***Xe*** is more like **/zi/** as it seems. Same with *xyr*.

References:
https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/xyr
https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/xe